# Efficient way of computing the cross products between two sets of vectors numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have two sets of 2000 3D vectors each, and I need to compute the cross product between each possible pair. I currently do it like this

```
for tx in tangents_x:
    for ty in tangents_y:
         cross = np.cross(tx, ty)
         (... do something with the cross variable...)
```

This works, but it's pretty slow. Is there a way to make it faster?

If I was interested in the element-wise product, I could just do the following

```
# Define initial vectors
tx = np.array([np.random.randn(3) for i in range(2000)])
ty = np.array([np.random.randn(3) for i in range(2000)])
# Store them into matrices
X = np.array([tx for i in range(2000)])
Y = np.array([ty for i in range(2000)]).T
# Compute the element-wise product
ew = X * Y
# Use the element_wise product as usual
for i,tx in enumerate(tangents_x):
    for j,ty in enumerate(tangents_y):
        (... use the element wise product of tx and ty as ew[i,j])
```

How can I apply this to the cross product instead of the element-wise one? Or, do you see another alternative?

Thanks much :)

Comment: Well, the cross product is also just a bunch of products, additions and subtractions.  You could decompose the arithmetic behind it and build it by your own again.  Did you consider that?  Maybe any code which isn't working?

Comment: Is this `cross product` as implemented in `np.cross`?  Or some version of `np.outer` or `np.dot`?

Comment: @hpaulj It is np.cross, as in the provided example

Comment: Can't you just do `np.cross(tangents_x[:,None,:], tangents_y)`?

Comment: @PaulPanzer I believe you are right, it turns out `np.cross` has full support for broadcasting...

Comment: Wait this is even faster than the currently fastest solution!!! Definitely write that down in an answer. But why does that work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like many numpy functions `cross` supports broadcasting, therefore you can simply do:

```
np.cross(tangents_x[:, None, :], tangents_y)
```

or - more verbose but maybe easier to read

```
np.cross(tangents_x[:, None, :], tangents_y[None, :, :])
```

This reshapes `tangents_x` and `tangents_y` to shapes `2000, 1, 3` and `1, 2000, 3`. By the rules of broadcasting this will be interpreted like two arrays of shape `2000, 2000, 3` where `tangents_x` is repeated along axis `1` and `tangents_y` is repeated along axis `0`.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to broadcasting.  I often wanted this feature and never found this simple way of doing it with implicit stuff.

Comment: Faster than anything but the compiled version below, and very compact and readable! My choice :)

Answer (score 4):

### Just write it out and compile it

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def calc_cros(vec_1,vec_2):
    res=np.empty((vec_1.shape[0],vec_2.shape[0],3),dtype=vec_1.dtype)
    for i in nb.prange(vec_1.shape[0]):
        for j in range(vec_2.shape[0]):
            res[i,j,0]=vec_1[i,1] * vec_2[j,2] - vec_1[i,2] * vec_2[j,1]
            res[i,j,1]=vec_1[i,2] * vec_2[j,0] - vec_1[i,0] * vec_2[j,2]
            res[i,j,2]=vec_1[i,0] * vec_2[j,1] - vec_1[i,1] * vec_2[j,0]
    
    return res
```

**Performance**

```
#create data
tx = np.random.rand(3000,3)
ty = np.random.rand(3000,3)
#don't measure compilation overhead
comb=calc_cros(tx,ty)

t1=time.time()
comb=calc_cros(tx,ty)
print(time.time()-t1)

This gives 0.08s for the two (3000,3) matrices.
```

Comment: If `numba` is an option, this is really marvelous :)

Answer (score 2):

`np.dot` is almost always going to be faster. So you could convert one of the vectors into a [matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Conversion_to_matrix_multiplication).

```
def skew(x):
    return np.array([[0, -x[2], x[1]],
                     [x[2], 0, -x[0]],
                     [-x[1], x[0], 0]])
```

On my machine this runs faster:

```
tx = np.array([np.random.randn(3) for i in range(100)])
ty = np.array([np.random.randn(3) for i in range(100)])

tt=time.clock()
for x in tx:
    for y in ty:
         cross = np.cross(x, y)
print(time.clock()-tt)
```

## 0.207 sec

```
tt=time.clock()
for x in tx:
    m=skew(x)
    for y in ty:
         cross = np.dot(m, y)
print(time.clock()-tt)
```

## 0.015 sec

This result may vary depending on the computer.

Comment: The skew trick is neat, but this still iterates in pure Python through all combinations.  For 3000×3000 elements it already took 5.4s on my computer.  Compare that to the `meshgrid` solution I provided.  It's considerable faster.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `np.meshgrid()` to build the combination matrix and then decompose the cross product.  The rest is fiddling around with the axes etc:

```
# build two lists of 5 3D vecotrs as example values:
a_list = np.random.randint(0, 10, (5, 3))
b_list = np.random.randint(0, 10, (5, 3))

# here the original approach using slow list comprehensions:
slow = np.array([[ np.cross(a, b) for a in a_list ] for b in b_list ])

# now the faster proposed version:
g = np.array([ np.meshgrid(a_list[:,i], b_list[:,i]) for i in range(3) ])
fast = np.array([ g[1,0] * g[2,1] - g[2,0] * g[1,1],
                  g[2,0] * g[0,1] - g[0,0] * g[2,1],
                  g[0,0] * g[1,1] - g[1,0] * g[0,1] ]).transpose(1, 2, 0)
```

I tested this with 10000×10000 elements (instead of the 5×5 in the example above) and it took 6.4 seconds with the fast version.  The slow version already took 27 seconds for 500 elements.

For your 2000×2000 elements the fast version takes 0.23s on my computer.  Fast enough for you?

Comment: Well this is definitely amazing! Thanks much :D will accept it tomorrow, if nothing even faster comes along

Comment: Also, this returns the transpose of the matrix I asked- fast[i,j] gives you the cross product of the i-th ty vector and the j-th tx vector, not the other way around. No big deal, as long as one notices it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a cartesian product to get all possible pairs

```
import itertools as it
all_pairs = it.product(tx, ty)
```

And then use map to loop over all pairs and compute the cross product:

```
map(lambda x: np.cross(x[0], x[1]), all_pairs)
```

Comment: The slow part here the iteration in pure Python.  You need to get rid of this and shove it off into the numpy implementation which is way faster.  Using `itertools` you still need to call `np.cross()` for each combination.