# Efficient way to calculate where a multivariable function takes values between a interval in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, math, numeric

I have two multivariate equations that determine the inverse kinematics of a robot. These equations depend on the variables theta1 and theta2 (the other variables are geometric constants)

```
import numpy as np

def x(theta1, theta2, w, h, L1, L2):
    sint1 = np.sin(theta1)
    cost1 = np.cos(theta1)
    sint2 = np.sin(theta2)
    cost2 = np.cos(theta2)

    i1 = L1 * (cost1 + cost2) + w
    j1 = L1 * (sint1 - sint2) - h
    D = np.sqrt((L1*(cost2-cost1)+w)**2+(L1*(sint2-sint1)+h)**2)
    a = (0.25)*np.sqrt((4*L2**2-D**2)*D**2)

    return i1/2 + 2*j1*a/(D**2)

def y(theta1, theta2, w, h, L1, L2):
    sint1 = np.sin(theta1)
    cost1 = np.cos(theta1)
    sint2 = np.sin(theta2)
    cost2 = np.cos(theta2)

    i2 = L1 * (sint1 + sint2) + h
    j2 = L1 * (cost1 - cost2) - w
    D = np.sqrt((L1*(cost2-cost1)+w)**2+(L1*(sint2-sint1)+h)**2)
    a = (0.25)*np.sqrt((4*L2**2-D**2)*D**2)

    return i2/2 - 2*j2*a/(D**2)
```

using these equations I calculate the determinant of the Jacobian matrix (partial derivative matrix) using the second order finite difference method

```
def det_jacobian(theta1, theta2, w, h, L1, L2,eps):
    dxdt1 = (-x(theta1+eps, theta2, w, h, L1, L2)+4*x(theta1, theta2, w, h, L1, L2)-3*x(theta1-eps, theta2, w, h, L1, L2))/(2*eps)
    dxdt2 = (-x(theta1, theta2+eps, w, h, L1, L2)+4*x(theta1, theta2, w, h, L1, L2)-3*x(theta1, theta2-eps, w, h, L1, L2))/(2*eps)
    dydt1 = (-y(theta1+eps, theta2, w, h, L1, L2)+4*y(theta1, theta2, w, h, L1, L2)-3*y(theta1-eps, theta2, w, h, L1, L2))/(2*eps)
    dydt2 = (-y(theta1, theta2+eps, w, h, L1, L2)+4*y(theta1, theta2, w, h, L1, L2)-3*y(theta1, theta2-eps, w, h, L1, L2))/(2*eps)  
    return dxdt1,dxdt2,dydt1,dydt2
```

Evaluated for the values of theta1 and theta2 belonging to an interval

```
theta1 = np.linspace(theta1_min,theta1_max,n)
theta2 = np.linspace(theta2_min,theta2_max,n)
theta1, theta2 = np.meshgrid(theta1,theta2)
```

What I want to know is if there is an efficient way (using numpy arrays) to calculate the values of x and y where the determinant takes values between -tol and tol (tol=1e-08). Currently I'm using two nested for cycles, but it is very slow

I have written a function using for cycles, but it is very slow

```
def singularidades(theta1_min,theta1_max, theta2_min,theta2_max, n,tol, w, h, L1, L2,eps):
    x_s = []
    y_s = []
    theta1_s = []
    theta2_s = []
    det = []
    theta1 = np.linspace(theta1_min,theta1_max,n)
    theta2 = np.linspace(theta2_min,theta2_max,n)
    theta1, theta2 = np.meshgrid(theta1,theta2)
    det_jac = det_jacobiano(theta1,theta2,w,h,L1,L2,eps)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if (g_tol[i,j] and l_tol[i,j]):
                x_s.append(x(theta1[i,j], theta2[i,j], w, h, L1, L2))
                y_s.append(y(theta1[i,j], theta2[i,j], w, h, L1, L2))
                theta1_s.append(theta1[i,j])
                theta2_s.append(theta2[i,j])
                det.append(det_jac[i,j])
   return x_s,y_s,theta1_s,theta2_s,det,(g_tol and l_tol)
```

Edit: I've modified the det_jacobian function to use it wiht scipy.optimize.root

```
def det_jacobiano(theta, w, h, L1, L2,eps):
    theta1,theta2 = theta
    dxdt1 = (-x(theta1+eps, theta2, w, h, L1, L2)+4*x(theta1, theta2, w, h, L1, L2)-3*x(theta1-eps, theta2, w, h, L1, L2))/(2*eps)
    dxdt2 = (-x(theta1, theta2+eps, w, h, L1, L2)+4*x(theta1, theta2, w, h, L1, L2)-3*x(theta1, theta2-eps, w, h, L1, L2))/(2*eps)
    dydt1 = (-y(theta1+eps, theta2, w, h, L1, L2)+4*y(theta1, theta2, w, h, L1, L2)-3*y(theta1-eps, theta2, w, h, L1, L2))/(2*eps)
    dydt2 = (-y(theta1, theta2+eps, w, h, L1, L2)+4*y(theta1, theta2, w, h, L1, L2)-3*y(theta1, theta2-eps, w, h, L1, L2))/(2*eps)  
    return dxdt1*dydt2 - dxdt2*dydt1
```

and I'm trying to find the roots using

```
initial_guess = [2.693, 0.4538]
result = optimize.root(det_jacobiano, initial_guess,tol=1e-8,args=(20,0,100,100,1e-10),method='lm')
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
TypeError: Improper input: N=2 must not exceed M=1
```

Comment: The way I read the question, OP wants to somehow automatically generate `x` and `y` values from the given interval limits, resulting in a 2-D array of results.  This requires adding some sort of step parameter in each direction.

Comment: Updated. I would greatly appreciate your help

Comment: Please look at your posting: you give us about 30 lines of computational code, and then ask a question about code that you did *not* include, and does *not* depend on the computations for its validity.

Comment: Maybe I'm explaining it wrong. I apologize for this because English is not my native language. 
Currently I have the function det_jacobian that works perfectly. What I want is to evaluate the det_jacobian for different values within a range (0, np.pi) and if the det_jacobian is between -1e-8 and 1e-8 place the values x and y in a list or array.

Comment: Please post the code you want us to improve.  For the problem you describe, you could replace that code with something called `complex_computation` that returns random values in the needed format.

Comment: I did it. I'll take a look

Comment: Apart from other solutions you can jit your function as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49883489/4045774 But you have to avoid lists (you can use numpy arrays and shrink them at the end). Using meshgrid also makes no sense. This should at least be 100x times faster than your current solution.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to implement numba

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a cycle for that. Your function can work with numpy arrays as well as single values:

```
def f(x,y):
    return np.sin(x + y) / np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)

x = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
y = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]

print(f(x, y))
```

will return:

```
[1.40480431, 1.37680175, 1.33087507, 1.26811839, 1.19001968]
```

which is an array of function values for each pair of x and y

Comment: I think we understood the question completely different. I'm not sure which interpretation is true though...

Comment: Yeah, that's confusing. Your approach also makes sense after reviewing the question again. I think the author needs to explain his problem deeper.

Comment: Updated. I would greatly appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to define:

```
def f(x,y,a):
    return np.sin(x + y) / np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2) - a
```

where `a` can take the limits of your interval and then calculate the roots `x0` and `y0` of this function using [`scipy.optimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#root-finding).

These roots correspond to the `x` and `y` values of your function between which the function returns the desired values.

Comment: Updated. I would greatly appreciate your help

Comment: If I understand your edit correctly, I think you should be able to calculate the roots of `det_jacobiano - g_tol` and the roots of `det_jacobiano - l_tol` so that the roots represent the `theta1` and `theta2` at which the function enters and leaves the tolerance range that you desire. I will update my answer to account for that. Please let me know if I understood you correctly.

Comment: Yes, it is. There is not a single root, they are a set of roots . Thank you. I was trying to ask a more general question but it turned out to be very vague

Comment: `scipy.optimize` should also work for multidimensional functions. I would think it should be much more efficient than the current looping approach.

Comment: I'll take a look. Thank you.

Comment: I'm trying to use `scipy.optimize` but I'm getting errors. Watch the question

Comment: Hi Pablo, I think you should open a new question to address the problems with `scipy.optimize`, as this question becomes way to large otherwise.

Comment: I've opened another question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49932428/5131259).If you have chance please take a look. I'll update the question when i get the solution